# Ok idk if its because im new to python or if i litterally broke something for my discord bot and need to redownload discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So this worked yesterday and now its popping up alot of errors since ive tried to update do a version of discord.py that will work for slash command and continue being developed.
Here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from apikeys import *

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=['!', '$', '_', '*', '$', '&'])


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('the bot is ready!')
    print('------------------')


@client.event
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello!')


@client.event
async def on_member_joined(member):
    with open('my_image.png', 'rb') as f:
        picture = discord.File(f)
        channel = client.get_channel(883152435357548596)
        await channel.send('Hello! Its not safe to go alone! Here take this!', file=picture)


@client.event
async def goodbye(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Bye! Have a good one!')


@client.event
async def selfdestruct(ctx):
    with open('explosion-boom.gif', 'rb') as f:
        gif = discord.File(f)
    await ctx.send('We going boom!!!', file=gif)


client.run(BOTTOKEN)
```

Its a rather easy bit of code to have the bot do some basic commands in discord. So I was extremally confused when it started shooting errors out in the dozens. If anyone knows what is happening here and how to fix it. Can you please explain to me what I did wrong and what the next course of action should be? I've tried moving code in and out of the document and editing my main.py but as far as I can tell I haven't done anything wrong on it
and here is what happens when I try to run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python Projects\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 349, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "E:\Python Projects\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 302, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Discord Bot\main.py", line 40, in <module>
    client.run(BOTTOKEN)
  File "E:\Python Projects\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 631, in run
    return future.result()
  File "E:\Python Projects\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 610, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Python Projects\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 573, in start
    await self.login(*args)
  File "E:\Python Projects\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 424, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip())
  File "E:\Python Projects\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 353, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000197FC310040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000197FC310040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000197FC310040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\ccarr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

As a new guy to python this is very intimidating.If you need any of the other documents that show up in the error section i will be more then happy to post them for review!

Comment: If I had to guess (and I'm really guessing because I haven't used discord.py) I'd say your token is incorrect. How do you have it stored? You don't need to give me the actual token, just where it is and the format: `DISCORD_TOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXX`

Comment: @Chrispresso I have my token stored in a file called apikeys.py thats why its imported as from apikeys import *  so if and when I use more api's with the bot all the keys are stored in a easy to read doc.

Comment: `LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.`, please learn how to read tracebacks, `discord.py` is not meant for beginners.

Comment: Ive already replaced the token 5 times now and that has not fixed the errors from still popping up. @ŁukaszKwieciński

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you typed correctly your discord token, and are you define "**BOTTOKEN**" in **client.run()**?

***Error 401 Unauthorized***:
The 401 Unauthorized Error is an HTTP response status code indicating that the request sent by the client could not be authenticated
This means that the **TOKEN** you entered is not valid or has been entered incorrectly.

Comment: I just went and redid the token to see if that would fix it. The same errors popped back up after regenerating the token and pasting it in the apikeys doc.

Comment: Try to put the token directly in the client.run and see if it will work.

Comment: Nope that did nothing. Still coming back with the same errors just with the token in place of BOTTOKEN. @Seekii

Comment: The only thing you can still try is to go to the discord developer portal and click on "Regenerate Token" and try to use the new token of bot. If that doesn't help, try contacting discord support.

Answer (score 0):

hi i will help you step by step:
First you have to put instead of

```py
@client.event
async def hello
```

this:

```py
@client.command()
async def hello("ctx"):
   await ctx.send("hi")
```

or if you want to be an event try this :

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   if message.content == "hello":
      await message.send("hi")
```

note: not all commands are events !
second help :
you just put a on_member_joined event. This event doesn't exist.. the real event is

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx):
with open('my_image.png', 'rb') as f:
        picture = discord.File(f)
        channel = client.get_channel(883152435357548596)
        await channel.send('Hello! Its not safe to go alone! Here take this!', file=picture)
```

third help:
i really dont know what you tried to do but i will try to help you in the 2 times:
if you want to do:

an event that detect when the user leave:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_leave(ctx)
   channel = client.get_channel("id of the channel")
   await ctx.channel.send ("bye !")
```

and if you want that to be a command you just have to put this but not `client.event` but `client.command()` like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def goodbye(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Bye! Have a good one!')
```

4. same error you put `@client.event` instead of `@client.command()`
   just put it like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def selfdestruct(ctx):
    with open('explosion-boom.gif', 'rb') as f:
        gif = discord.File(f)
    await ctx.send('We going boom!!!', file=gif)
```

5. and the last error (im not sure thats an error)

just put instead of `client.run(BOTTOKEN)` put `client.run("the token")